# how to change \\n to \n in perl

Tags: perl

I have a $string including special char following slash such as "1234\\n567\\t";
Note "\\n" and "\\t" are all two char, not three char. so when they are displayed, they are displayed as "\n" and "\t".

For some reason, I need to change the string as : "1234\n567`efg\t". How to do that in a simple way?
Here is my code, which I think can be improved:

```
            @src_array = split(//, $string);  
            @des_array = ();    
            $size = $#src_array + 1;  
            $converting = 0;  
            for ($i = 0, $j = 0; $i< $size; $i++){  
               if ($converting == 1) {  
                            # convert and replace '\\n' with '\n'  
                    $des_array[$j++] = $slash_char{$src_array[$i]};  
                    $converting = 0;  
               }  
               elsif ($src_array[$i] == '\\'){  
                    $converting = 1;  
               }  
               else {  
                    $des_array[$j++] = $src_array[$i];  
               }  
            }

my %slash_char = (  
        'a' => '\a',  
        'b' => '\b'    
...  
);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert $string from "1234\\n567\\t" to "1234\n567\t"?

Comment: It would be helpful to show an accurate assignment of your sample input data to `$string`.  It could be `$string = q{1234\\n567\\t};` or `$string = qq{1234\\n567\\t};`, for example, which give two quite different starting points.  It would also be helpful to have an accurate desired output string: `$result = qq{1234\n567\t};` or whatever is correct.

Comment: @Jonathan `q{1234\\n567\\t}` and `qq{1234\\n567\\t}` are identical strings (and neither one contains two backslashes in a row :)

Comment: @hobbs: what is the difference between single quoting and double quoting?  And what is the difference between `qq{...}` and `q{...}`.

Comment: @Jonathan, backslashes do not interpolate inside single quotes, _unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated._ (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) `qq` and `q` are double & single quoting with alternate delimiters, respectively.

Comment: @hobbs, @cjm: OK - yes; the strings are the same...I seem to have overlooked something.  However, the closely related pair of strings: `q{1234\n567\t}` and `qq{1234\n567\t}` are different.  I somehow forgot or was unaware that backslashes were partially interpreted in single-quote strings; variable substitution and other such mechanisms are disabled when single quoted, of course.  All the more reason to request the OP to provide the data that they are working with.

Answer (score 3):

Why not:

```
s/\\n/\n/g;
s/\\t/\t/g;
```

It would be nice to use `tr///`, but that can't transform two characters to one.

Comment: re: tr/// - yes it can transform two characters into one, e.g. `$x = "aa"; $x =~ tr/a/a/s;` -  the 's' (squash) option removes duplicate translated characters

Comment: @plusplus: I'll clarify - but it cannot convert a pair of characters into a single character as required to achieve a mapping from `q{\n}` to `qq{\n}`.

Comment: Doing it as separate substitutions doesn't allow for backslashes to escape themselves.  That wasn't an explicit requirement, but it seems likely the OP wants that.  His code would do that, if `%slash_char` was set up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the easy way is to use [String::Escape](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aEscape):

```
use String::Escape 'unbackslash';

my $string = "1234\\n567\\t";
my $new_string = unbackslash($string);
```